# how to find a function that minimizes the other function with a known function

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint, variational-calculus

The problem that i am facing is that of energy minimization. I have a function called `totalenergy` which is sum of two functions the elastic energy and the surface tension `surfacetension`.

```
totalenergy = k/2 (Integrate[r[angle], {angle, 0, Pi}] - c)^2 + 
Integrate[surfacetension[angle] r[angle]^2 Sin[angle], {angle, 0, Pi}]
```

`k` and `c` are constants in the above equation and angle is the angle in polar coordinates.

the user defines how `surfacetension` should should look like:

for example:

```
surfacetension[ang_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 0.2], ang] + 0.5

Plot[surfacetension[x], {x, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> {{0, Pi}, {0, Max[Pi]}}]
```

[image]

Now i wish to find the unknown profile `r[angle]` such that `totalenergy` is minimized for the known profile `surfacetension[angle]` for `0 <= angle <= Pi` . This is precisely where I am stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

with marmots suggestion i tried the following code:

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
surfacetension[ang_ /; ang <= Pi] := PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 0.2], ang] + 0.5;
surfacetension[ang_ /; ang > Pi] := PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 0.2], 2 Pi - ang] + 0.5;
rsol[angle_, constant_] := r[angle] /. Solve[VariationalD[0.5 (r[angle] - 1)^2 +
surfacetension[angle] r[angle], r[angle], angle] == constant, r[angle]][[1]];
PolarPlot[rsol[\[Theta], 1], {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

**however what i expect to get is the following**

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for an exact solution? Otherwise you could discretise your unknown profile and you would then have a classical optimisation problem (which does not mean that it easy to solve; will probably depend on the number of unknowns), instead of a functional optimisation one.

Comment: @anderstood actually right now i just need to crudely see what the function looks like. I am new to this area of Mathematica. Is it possible for you to post something as an answer

Comment: Before being an "area of Mathematica", it is an area of mathematics. I suggest reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation. I don't have time to investigate your problem right now but I might try later.

Comment: @anderstood looks exactly what is needed. thanks will read this up

Comment: @anderstood actually having read it, i do not think how i can apply it, especially because i do not have any `r'[angle]` or derivative term in my equation.

Comment: @AliHashmi I agree that this is not a standard problem that can be solved immediately with `EulerEquations`. However, I believe that you can still compute the differential of the above energy functional. When I do this on paper, I get an equation telling me that `r[alpha]=constant/(surfacetension[alpha Sin[alpha])` (no guarantee). Inserting this back and minimizing the result w.r.t. constant should give you the result (again no guarantee).

Comment: @marmot let me try. Thanks for the pointer

Comment: @AliHashmi I tried to do the computation. However, there is a problem at the boundaries. You may redefine `r` to `r[angle] Sqrt[Sin[angle]]`. Most likely there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: @marmot can you post your answer. maybe we can work on it

Comment: @marmot my `r` is already in written as a function of angle `r[angle]` everywhere in the equation

Comment: Are you sure that you mean $(\int \dots d\theta - c)^2$ and not $\int( \dots -c)^2 d\theta$?

Comment: You might pretend `r[theta]` is a rational function of fixed degree in numerator and denominator, write it explicitly as such with symbolic coefficients, and have them as variables to be found in the optimization. This is sensible if the function can be accurately modeled by a Pade approximation. Might require constraints so that `r[0]==r[2Pi]`.

Comment: @anderstood yes its the former.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau could you kindly post it as an answer if convenient. Hope to understand it better

Comment: @DanielLichtblau i made the edit to the last code. the `surfacetension[0]` is equal to that at `2Pi`

Comment: @AliHashmi I do not see that this is the solution I proposed. In `rsol[angle_, constant_] := r[angle] /. Solve[VariationalD[0.5 (r[angle] - 1)^2 +
surfacetension[angle] r[angle], r[angle], angle] == constant, r[angle]][[1]];` I'd drop the first term and change the second term `surfacetension[angle] r[angle]^2 Sin[angle]`. In addition, I was and am wondering if @anderstood is right with her/his comment.

Comment: @marmot i definitely modified your code. i need some time to understand fully what is going on. but usually spring energy is written in for of `1/2 k* (extendedlength - restinglength)^2`. The extended length is calculated using the arc length and resting length is a constant

Comment: @AliHashmi Sorry, I disagree. Rather, I believe that there should be a `(r'[angle])^2` term. But this is not a physics forum. The only point of my answer below is that, for some reason, Mathematica does not yet deal with general functionals and one has to do the functional derivative by hand. I also believe that the generalization outlined in my "answer" should be straightforward to implement.

Comment: Coding what I suggested might be more time than I have right now. In the unlikely event that I get some moments I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that the following is to be considered an answer but may contain some steps towards an answer. The total energy is a functional of $r$, $E[r]$. You're looking for an extremum of this functional. The first term $E_1[r]$ is the square of a functional, 
$$ E_1[r]=\frac{k}{2}\left[\int\limits_0^\pi r(\alpha)\,\text{d}\alpha-c\right]^2=:\frac{k}{2}S[r]^2.$$
Using the chain rule, one obtains the differential
$$ \frac{\delta E_1}{\delta r}(\alpha)=k\,S[r]\,\frac{\delta S}{\delta r}(\alpha)=k\,S[r]\,\cdot 1.$$
The second term can be treated with Mathematica's `VariationalD`. So the partial answer is the code

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
totalenergy := k/2 (NIntegrate[r[angle], {angle, 0, Pi}] - c)^2 + NIntegrate[surfacetension[angle] r[angle]^2 Sin[angle] , {angle, 0, Pi}];
dtotalenergy = k (Integrate[r[angle], {angle, 0, Pi}] - c) + VariationalD[surfacetension[angle] r[angle]^2 Sin[angle], r[angle], angle];
surfacetension[ang_] := PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 0.2], ang] + 0.5;
rsol[angle_, constant_] := r[angle] /.Solve[VariationalD[surfacetension[angle] r[angle]^2 Sin[angle], r[angle], 
   angle] == constant, r[angle]][[1]];
```

This seems to fix the functional form of $r$ to be
$$ r(\alpha) = \frac{0.5 \text{constant} \csc
   (\alpha)}{0.5\, +1.99471
   e^{-12.5 \alpha^2}}.$$
The constant can be fixed by requiring that $\frac{\delta E}{\delta r}$ vanishes. However, I have problems with the integral. That's why I was proposing to redefine $r\to r\sqrt{\sin\alpha}$. As mentioned above, I'll be happy to erase this partial answer.

EDIT: replaced `:=` before `=`. Also restarted the kernel, and the code went through.

Comment: thanks. can you quickly check the code for typos. because i can see `:=` missing after `rsol`. can you run with the kernel restart and check if you get the answer that you have mentioned below

Comment: what if instead of `r[angle]^2 Sin[angle]` we just have `r[range]`. I realized I might be mistaken with the inclusion of the `square` and the `Sin` term

Comment: kindly see the edit. i made the `surfacetension` at angle = 0 and 2Pi the same